# Mathjax \text{} with greek letters inside

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, mathjax

I am trying to use mathjax in Jupyter Notebook, and trying to render the following
[image]

in Latex typesettings I can render only the followin:
`\varepsilon-\text{greedy}(Q)$\`
[image]

**As you can see the `dash` is very long and adds extra space around dash.**

If i move the epsolon within the `\text` expression the result will be:
`\text{\varepsilon-greedy}(Q)$\`
[image]\

The `dash`  has no problem bu the epsilon is not rendered.

How can I render the epsilon as intend.

**Resolved: UPDATE**
**Resolved: UPDATE2**

That is not the answer for rendering the same outout is just move the `dash` into the `\text`
`\varepsilon\text{-greedy}(Q)$\`
[image]

Comment: omg, the answer is move dash into ```\text``` - ```\varepsilon\text{-greedy}(Q)$\```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `\text{\varepsilon-greedy}(Q)` is not valid LaTeX.  The `\varepsilon` macro is a math-mode macro, and is not allowed in text mode, as it appears here, so it would cause an error message in actual LaTeX.

MathJax is designed to process primarily math-mode material, so it does not process macros in text mode, so `\varepsilon` will be displayed verbatim.  If you want to use it in text mode, you could use `\text{$\varepsilon$-greedy}(Q)` to temporarily enter math mode within text mode.

MathJax version 3 has a `textmacros` extension that allows processing of some macros in text mode, but that is not available in version 2, which is what is used on StackExchange.  (They are using a four-year-old version of MathJax here.)

Comment: Many thanks David for you detailed answer, i will follow your solution.