# How to configure R Markdown to use the "textmacros" MathJax extension for HTML rendering?

Tags: html, r-markdown, knitr, mathjax

I'd like to configure my R Markdown document to use the `textmacros` MathJax extension for HTML rendering (knitting) in RStudio. I was unsuccessful in trying to apply the instructions provided at https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/textmacros.html in a `include: in_header:` file specified in my YAML header (see the example below).

I'm using RStudio ***2022.12.0** Build 353* (version available in my workplace).

**Context**
My goal is to get similar rendering with LaTeX text commands (e.g., `\text{}` or `\texttt{}`) whether I *Knit to PDF* or *Knit to HTML*  with MathJax. E.g., while `$\texttt{my\_var}$` renders to `my_var` in PDF, it renders to `my\_var` in HTML with MathJax by default. Using the `textmacros` extension would (supposedly) render it to `my_var` in HTML as well.

Note: HTML rendering with `webtex` works fine in this case, but I'd like to have the option to use  `mathjax` as well.

**Example**

R Markdown document:

```
---
title: "My Doc"
output:
  html_document:
    #math_method: webtex
    math_method: mathjax
    includes:
      in_header: header.html
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
---

Test formula: $\texttt{my\_var} * 2 + 1$
```

header.html file (source: https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/textmacros.html):

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({ 
    loader: {load: ['[tex]/textmacros']},
    tex: {packages: {'[+]': ['textmacros']}}
  });
</script>
```

The following solution (without the `textmacros` extension) would work but it is less than ideal to say the least...

````
---
title: "My Doc"
output:
  html_document:
    math_method: mathjax
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
---

```{asis, echo=knitr::is_html_output()}
Test formula: $\texttt{my_var} * 2 + 1$
```
```{asis, echo=(knitr::is_html_output() == FALSE)}
Test formula: $\texttt{my\_var} * 2 + 1$
```
````

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer to question [Mathjax \text{} with greek letters inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74816183/mathjax-text-with-greek-letters-inside/74825914#74825914) applies to my issue as well. My version of RStudio (2022.12.0 Build 353) uses MathJax 2.7.2 while the `textmacros` extension was introduced in MathJax 3.